# Is it possible to lazy-load language mode packages?

Tags: init-file, major-mode, autoload, load

Most of the packages I currently use are major modes for various languages that are only included in the off-chance I load a file of that type.

Is there a way to postpone loading them at startup in my `init` file - until a filename with a particular file extension is loaded?

---

*Note that I'm not familiar with exactly how emacs packages are already supposed to be using auto-load, but emacs without many packages starts nearly instantly, and with them - takes ~2seconds. I've profiled the startup and while some package a clearly worse offenders than others - this isn't one single package at fault. So I was interested to lazy load where possible.*

Comment: [`autoload`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html)

Comment: If you mean package.el packages, then this should already be happening by default, and is arguably a bug in the package if it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `autoload` rather than `require`

example with `yaml-mode`

```el
(autoload 'yaml-mode "yaml-mode" nil t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.yml$" . yaml-mode))
```

Answer (score 1):

An interesting and efficient method for your goal is the macro [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package), excerpt from author's readme:

> "The use-package macro allows you to isolate package configuration in
>   your .emacs file in a way that is both performance-oriented and, well,
>   tidy. I created it because I have over 80 packages that I use in
>   Emacs, and things were getting difficult to manage. Yet with this
>   utility my total load time is around 2 seconds, with no loss of
>   functionality!"

Some more explanations can be seen in this [video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=2TSKxxYEbII).
Many users also use this, for various packages configurations [this](https://github.com/angrybacon/dotemacs/blob/master/dotemacs.org#d-features) is also a good reference.